# get current date in Http Live Streaming Android 3.0+

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, http-live-streaming

I'm searching about how can I get the current time of an HTTP Live Stream (HLS) with the default MediaPlayer in Android 3.0 or 4.0. The tag in the m3u8 file is: #EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME. I need that time only for displaying purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this isn't exposed in Android. I think you'll need to get creative... Maybe you can retrieve the m3u8 file separately, and display something based on what you parse.

Comment: that is exactly what i'm doing now, I thought I could get that information natively